# bash: grep row if fields are equal

Tags: regex, awk, find, cut

I need to find all the rows which have the same content in all the columns, by examining all CSV files in the system. Example:

```
MYCOL;1;2;3;4
MYCOL2;2;3;4;5
MYCOL3;1;1;1;1
MYCOL4;;;;
```

In my example, I would need to grep for MYCOL3 and MYCOL4, as they both have the same field content for all columns, it doesn't matter if there is no content.

I thought about something like this:

```
find / -name *.csv | xargs awk -F "," '{col[$1,$2]++} END {for(i in col) print i, col[i]}'
```

But I'm missing the comparison between all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `grep` command:

```sh
$ grep -xE '[^;]*(;[^;]*)\1+' ip.txt
MYCOL3;1;1;1;1
MYCOL4;;;;
```

- `-x` to match only whole line
- `[^;]*` first field
- `(;[^;]*)` capture `;` followed by non `;` characters (i.e. second field)
- `\1+` use the captured field to be repeated as many times as needed till end of the line

If input has only ASCII characters, you could use `LC_ALL=C grep <...>` to get the results faster.

If you have `GNU grep`, you can use `-r` option and `--include=` option instead of `find+grep`

Also, use `find <...> -exec grep <...> {} +` instead of `find + xargs`

Just did a sample speed check, this regex may be too bad to use with BRE/ERE. Use `grep -P` if available. Otherwise, use `awk` or `perl`.

```sh
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' ip.txt | shuf > f1
$ du -h f1
53M    f1

$ time LC_ALL=C grep -xE '[^;]*(;[^;]*)\1+' f1 > t1
real    0m44.815s

$ time LC_ALL=C grep -xP '[^;]*(;[^;]*)\1+' f1 > t2
real    0m0.507s

$ time perl -ne 'print if /^[^;]*(;[^;]*)\1+$/' f1 > t3
real    0m3.973s

$ time LC_ALL=C awk -F ';' '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != $2) next} 1' f1 > t4
real    0m2.728s

$ diff -sq t1 t2
Files t1 and t2 are identical
$ diff -sq t1 t3
Files t1 and t3 are identical
$ diff -sq t1 t4
Files t1 and t4 are identical
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex approach using `awk`:

```
awk -F ';' '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != $2) next} 1' file
```

```
MYCOL3;1;1;1;1
MYCOL4;;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F";" -v OFS=";" ' { a=$0; $1=""; c=split($0,ar,$2); if(length($0)==NF-1 || c==NF) print a } ' gipsy.txt
MYCOL3;1;1;1;1
MYCOL4;;;;
$
```